# Non-void function used in void context?

Tags: function, void, system-verilog

I am using SystemVerilog. My code is:

```
function write_pixel_data(datastr ds);
 /* some stuff here... but no return */
endfunction
```

then i am calling my function like:

```
write_pixel_data(someval);
```

And i get the vcs warning:

```
Warning-[SV-NFIVC] Non-void function used in void context.
```

But i am not returning anything, i know i can cast the function call to void to get rid of the warning. But why it gives this warning??!!

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you haven't declared the function as `void` and you call it without assigning the return value to anything, you'll see this error. Simple fix:

```
function void write_pixel_data(datastr ds);
 /* some stuff here... but no return */
endfunction
```

Careful though, you can't do anything that 'takes time' in a function. You'll need a `task` for that.

Answer (score 3):

A function declared with an implicit type returns `logic`. You must explicitly declare the return type to be void if that is your intention.